# StreamLabsChatBot Your Platform (cli) is not supported by PyAutoGUI

Tags: python, c++, youtube, minecraft

Im trying to make a Youtube Plays with python and streamlabs chatbot and i am using pyautogui for clicking keys, when message is "W" press W for example

so well, i tried to import the script into Streamlabs chatbot but it says

"Your platform (cli) is not supported by PyAutoGUI"

i cant seem to find anything that could fix that, so i come to ask my question here
and hope i can  get some help

Comment: Do you have the documentation for PyAutoGUI handy?